Euclid: are any of his propositions used to find logarithms?
Does Euclid have a proposition or a series of propositions used to find logarithms of lengths?
Maybe Napier borrowed some propositions for his publication and am curious about this.

No?...  Archimedes Sand Reckoner gets close.  This is discussed in Ian Bruce's "Napier's logarithms", https://doi.org/10.1119/1.19387 .

$b^p = y, log(y) = p$ and $log^-1(b^p) = p$, so if you can plot $b^x = y$ I would assume you would be able to understand logarithms historically. Correct?

Ptolemy used greek letters (1-9 in one-to-one relationship with alphabet order), where $10^n * a_n$ and $n+1$ every 9 letters, using 'o' as zero.  Then when the letters are all used to the end, commas are used in front for higher bases. Forming a sequence of digits similar to base positional system that is more explicit.  So I suspect he must have known inverse function of $b^x = y$

Napier imagined logarithms as particles moving on a line from a common starting point, with one particle marking constant intervals at steady speed, the other with speed proportional to distance from the start. So it was based on an idea of accumulating ratios, which goes back to Eudoxus (summarized in Elements book 5). I would say Euclid's propositions are useful for it only in the sense that he presents ratios, which are of course very widely useful.

Side note, records on Napier's education are sparse, but he knew Greek and would almost certainly have read Euclid, and likely Archimedes.

@RobinSparrow So the logarithm requires use of infinitesimal calculus to set the limit of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} L = (1 + 1/n)^n$?

No, Napier predated calculus by about 50-100 years. You are probably thinking of Euler deriving e via calculus.
